# How check from code if some language is installed in Tesseract API?

Tags: c++, tesseract

I have a problem with Tesseract API.

I want to check from C++ code which languages is available to perform OCR in. I want to say to user that some language package is not installed.

To enable some language it is needed to install `tesseract-lang-xxx` package.

Eventually it will be OK if I can check that in CMake.

Comment: Can you query `tessdata` folder for `*.traineddata` files?

Comment: Yeah, that is some idea

Comment: Re-inviting wheel? This is exactly what GetAvailableLanguagesAsVector does (via [addAvailableLanguages](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/12c1225a5f9c4e057c998f9407d581a171ab4a9e/src/api/baseapi.cpp#L120) Read the source. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of problem you have with tesseract API? Is not [GetAvailableLanguagesAsVector](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/e250f3422d8346ac3b0468168845ee5a2cafc511/src/api/baseapi.h#L265) sufficient for you?

Comment: It looks like sth I've looked for. I try it, thank you. I didn't see this earlier.

Comment: This method returns languages that are used in `Init()` method. It is not needed to have some language installed to use it in `Init()` method. So `GetAvailableLanguagesAsVector()` doesn't say what languages have been installed and available to use.

Comment: Your description is not correct: `GetAvailableLanguagesAsVector()` does not returns languages that are used in `Init()`! Function [GetInitLanguagesAsString](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/e250f3422d8346ac3b0468168845ee5a2cafc511/src/api/baseapi.h#L253) does that.

Comment: I tested it and it does.